# Converting an entire C# project to C++

Tags: c#, c++, code-generation

I have a personal project written in C#, but due to some problems and platform dependency I decided to rewrite the program in C++.

The project contains dozens of classes and thousands of lines of code. I would like to know if there is a way to **at least** generate the correct header files, and the cpp files with only the method stubs.

I know that direct code generation is not possible, but generating just the skeleton of the program would be a big help.

My C# project is a Visual Studio 2013 project and **I want to convert it to native c++ so no CLI included**.

What I would like to do is this:

1. List item
2. Grab each class in the project.
3. Generate header file based on the class.
4. Generate .cpp file with method stubs based on the class.

Comment: What you're trying to do doesn't seem reasonably possible.  C# has a CLI dependency, so any direct translation to native code would be impractical without it.

Comment: That doesn't seem feasible at all, but my best try would be trying to use some reverse engineering tool to extract a UML model from your code and then a code generation tool to create the C++ esqueleton from that model. I'm not posting it as an answer because I can't tell any specific tools that support this workflow, if there are any (which I think there should be).

Comment: Yea this UML reverse-generate seems like a good idea, and this is very close to what I thought first.

Comment: You might be better off to look at third party options that will make .net code work across different platforms.  Mono comes to mind.

Comment: "but due to some problems and platform dependency" I think perhaps if you described these in more detail there maybe some suggestions that can be made on how to keep the code base in C# and overcome these problems.

Comment: I'd think that C#-reflection would be good for exactly this kind of job:  Use reflection to enumerate all the classes, and their methods, and members, and write them out in a C++-formatted version.  There may be some types that do not translate well, but it would definitely give you a starting point.

Answer (score 5):

If you're trying to avoid C++/CLI, automatic conversion really won't make sense.

The main issue isn't the classes and your code - it's that the underlying frameworks are so dramatically different that you'll likely need to restructure, rearchitect, and change your approach in order to make things work properly in the native version.

Many of the concepts that will be commonplace in C# will just not map over the same way into C++.